# Lastrow variable into a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has question been asked several times and with good response but i am still unable to get this problem working.
After i find the last row of a column (assume there are no blank values in the column) i want to use the lastrow variable in my formula

The following works fine , to copy the formula down to the last row

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' obtains the last row value

Worksheets("Test").Range("i2:i" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(-- 
($B$2:$B$189<=B2)*(B2<=$D$2:$D$189))"
```

what i need to do is to use i.e concatenate the lastrow variable vice the 
    $B$189 and $D$189 references inside the formula

I tried the following without success;

```
Worksheets("Test").Range("i2:i" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(-- 
(""$B$2:$B$"" & LastRow<=B2)*(B2<=""$D$2:$D$"" & LastRow))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with quotation marks and concatenation in the formula.

Try,

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$" & LastRow & "<=B2)*(B2<=$D$2:$D$" & LastRow & "))"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more careful with your addresses and formulas.  Looks like you are trying to populate column `I` with your formula, so you should count the rows in column `H` (columns number 8) - `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row`.  If you are not sure how to enter a formula using VBA, try recording it using the `Record Macro` function and examine the code for ideas.  The code below should help you with your task:

```
    Dim LastRow As Double

    With Worksheets("Test")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("i2:i" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(-- ($B$2:$B$" & LastRow & "<=B2)*(B2<=$D$2:$D$" & LastRow & "))"
    End With
```